# iOS App Requires arm64?

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7, arm64

I uploaded my app to Xcode where it says the build requires arm64. This excludes iPhones 5/5c and lower from using the app. However, I want iPhone 5/5c to be able to use the app and must have required arm64 by mistake. I think it must be something in the info.plist but have no idea.

Things I have checked:

(1) The info.plist does not have a RequiredDeviceCapabilities line.

(2) Under Build Settings in Xcode, armv7, armv7s, and arm64 are all valid architectures.

Any help you can offer would be incredible. I have attached a screenshot of my info.plist and if you think it may be something else and need more information please comment and let me know! Thanks!

[image: info.plist Image]

Comment: Could you post the error message you get?

Comment: @Jelly So there is no error message. The app builds just fine, but in Xcode when I click on the build it says it requires arm64. So essentially I just want to figure out how to not require this so more people can use the app (iPhone 5/5c users).

Comment: Well iPhone 5/5c have `arm64` CPU architecture so you need it. Does your project have and frameworks in it?

Comment: @Jelly Yes I do have a good number of frameworks. I will update my post to include a picture of my frameworks, and thanks for your help!

Comment: You do realise that apps can have multiple CPU architectures.  When it says it requires `arm64` that doesn't mean you cannot include `armv7` and `armv7s`.

Comment: Some or those framework might not be compiled for `arm64`, you should check the error you get in issues navigator.

Comment: @trojanfoe you are mistaken. If it requires arm64, it will not be able to upload to iPhone 5 or 5c as they do not have arm64 capabilities. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422447/what-iphone-devices-will-run-on-armv7s-and-arm64

Comment: @Jelly See the issue is that I don't get an error message. I don't have an iPhone 5 or 5c to test the app on. The app runs on the simulator.

Comment: @LodgeApps Not true at all.

Answer (score 2):

*Note - this answer has been refined based on the comments to my original answer.*

Apps uploaded to the App Store require 64-bit support and the normally accepted method is to build the app with multiple-CPU support.

You want build active architectures set to YES for the Debug configuration and NO for the Release configuration.

This does not change the arm64 requirement, as that is not an Xcode requirement, but rather an App Store requirement. In effect there should be nothing to change from the default Xcode project template.

So, simply go to build settings > "build active architecture only" and set it to "NO"

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This is completely wrong.  Apps uploaded to the App Store require 64-bit support and the normally accepted method is to build the app with multiple-CPU support,  You seem completely unaware that iOS and OSX executables and libraries are *fat* where-in they can contain the same code compiled for different CPUs.  The host system simply uses the CPU most appropriate to them.

Comment: You want *build active architectures* set to *YES* for the *Debug* configuration and *NO* for the *Release* configuration.  This does not change the `arm64` requirement, as that is not an Xcode requirement, but rather an App Store requirement.  In effect there should be nothing to change from the default Xcode project template.

Comment: @LodgeApps I highly suggest you edit your answer to reflect the conversation below